# Laravel 5.4 get related data and display

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using [this repo](https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-5-boilerplate) as starting point for my project.

I have a `user` table and `clubs` table. `User` can have one club and `club` is attached to one `user`.

So i defined `hasOne` relationship in `clubs` table like below.

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

`clubs` table has `user_id` column.

I could not get correct data on my `index` page to display `userName` of the `User`.

I am using `ClubsRepository` to display data.

Below is the code for it.

```
public function __invoke(ManageClubRequest $request)
{
    return Datatables::of($this->clubs->getForDataTable())
        ->escapeColumns(['clubName', 'sort'])
        ->addColumn('user', function ($clubs) {
            return $clubs->user->pluck('first_name');
        })
        ->addColumn('actions', function ($clubs) {
            return $clubs->action_buttons;
        })
        ->withTrashed()
        ->make(true);
}
```

In repository below is my 'getFromDataTable()' method

```
public function getForDataTable()
{
    return $this->query()
        ->with('user')
        ->select([
            'clubs.id',
            'clubs.clubName',
            'clubs.description',
            'clubs.user_id',
            'clubs.created_at',
            'clubs.updated_at',
        ]);
}
```

My `index.blade` code is below

```
<table id="clubs-table" class="table">
   <tr>
       <th>clubName</th>
       <th>description</th>
       <th>userName</th>
       <th>created</th>
       <th>last_updated</th>          
  </tr>
 </table>

<script>
  $(function () {
        $('#clubs-table').DataTable({
            dom: 'lfrtip',
            processing: false,
            serverSide: true,
            autoWidth: false,
            ajax: {
                url: '{{ route("admin.access.clubs.get") }}',
                type: 'post',
                data: {status: 1, trashed: false},
                error: function (xhr, err) {
                    if (err === 'parsererror')
                        console.log(err);
                }
            },
            columns: [
                {data: 'clubName', name: 'clubs.clubName'},
                {data: 'description', name: 'clubs.description'},
                {data: 'user', name: 'user.first_name', sortable:false},
                {data: 'created_at', name: 'clubs.created_at'},
                {data: 'updated_at', name: 'clubs.updated_at'}
            ],
        });
    });
</script>
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: @AaronFahey tried that but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query to get User's with their clubs data

```
   User::with(array('clubs' => function($q) {
     }))->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using the wrong kind of relationship - if the clubs table has a user_id column, that means it `belongs to` the user, not that it `has one` user.

Assuming each user can have multiple clubs, what you want is

```
// in the User model
public function clubs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Club::class);
}

// in the Clubs model
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

---

In addition, I'm not familiar with datatables, but one thing worth noting is that you don't actually execute the query in your `getForDataTable()` method. It lacks a `->get()` or similar. There's also the problem that `$this->query()` doesn't seem like the most efficient way of doing what you're trying to do, but it's hard to tell for sure.

And in this line:

```
return Datatables::of($this->clubs->getForDataTable())
```

Are the clubs a collection of multiple clubs? Because you can't call a model method on a collection of objects.

Comment: I tried this and now its displaying all the users `first_name` as array.

Comment: I've updated some more - if it doesn't work, could you please describe more specifically what the `$this->clubs` is, and what you're trying to call?